# Verify day falls in month

Tags: date, cast, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with `Xday`, `Xmonth`, and `Xyear` columns but the data was user generated and apparently done without adequate input validation so some of it is nonsense.  It's easy enough to do things like `Xday between 1 and 31`, but I still get an error when doing `date(Xyear, Xmonth, Xday)` if for example someone put in February 30th.

Is there some way I can either validate the date prior to doing the conversion to the date type or a way to just toss out the rows causing errors instead of throwing the exception?

Comment: `temp = date(Xyear, 1, 1)` -> `temp = DATEADD(temp, INTERVAL Xmonth MONTH)` -> `temp = DATEADD(temp, INTERVAL Xday - 1 DAY)` -> compare `Xday` and `EXTRACT(DAY FROM temp)`, compare `Xmonth` and `EXTRACT(MONTH FROM temp)` - both must be equal. Combine this everything into one single expression.

Comment: Prefixing with `SAFE.` worked.  Thanks!

Comment: @BobbieD Added as answer so you can marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the prefix `SAFE` so the `DATE` function returns NULL instead of throwing an error.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators